# Regex to find a specific anchor tag that have href with a specific domain and nofollow

Tags: regex

I have a string that contains html I want a regex that get me the string that has  with a specific domain name and has noFollow

I have found this would will do work on the domain name but does not include nofollow condition
(<a\s*(?!.*\brel=)[^>]*)(href="https?://)((?stackoverflow)[^"]+)"([^>]*)>

let's say the domain name I want is stackoverflow
Example:

```
- "<a href="stackoverflow.com" rel = "nofollow">click here </a>" this would match
- "<a href="stackoverflow.com"> would not match since it has no follow
- "<a href="google.com" rel = "nofollow"> would not match
```

Comment: What language do you use for executing regex?

Comment: I am trying the regex in a PostgreSQL query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's bit hard to match a HTML tag with specific condition, but the following regex should do it:

```sql
select regexp_match(str, '<a((?:\s+(([^\/=''"<>\s]+)(=((''[^'']*'')|("[^"]*")|([^\s<>''"=`]+)))?)))* href=((''(https?:\/\/)?stackoverflow\.com[^'']*'')|("(https?:\/\/)?stackoverflow\.com[^"]*"))((?: (([^\/=''"<>\s]+)(=((''[^'']*'')|("[^"]*")|([^\s<>''"=`]+)))?)))*\s+rel=("nofollow"|''nofollow'')((?: (([^\/=''"<>\s]+)(=((''[^'']*'')|("[^"]*")|([^\s<>''"=`]+)))?)))*\/?>') from tes;
```

It's *really* hard to read, but basically most of the regex is there for matching attributes. The important thing for you is to find `stackoverflow\.com` (**which can be found 2 times**; one for `href` with single quote and second for double quote) and replace it with whatever domain you need (and don't forget to escape it properly).

### Some notes

I don't know which regexp function you want to use, but you should be able to use it with whatever regexp function you need. Another thing is that your example `<a href="stackoverflow.com" rel = "nofollow">click here </a>` won't be matched, because you have spaces between attribute name and `=` sign (i don't know if this is valid HTML or not). It will work with this `<a href="stackoverflow.com" rel="nofollow">click here </a>`. If you need to match addresses which might include spaces between `=` signs just comment me and I'll try to edit the regex.